# Is there any way to Wrap chartNew.js with angular.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I was wondering, if we have angular js Wrapper for ChartNewjs (https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/) or a way to do so.

Comment: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ based on chart.js

Comment: Thank bro, But chart js do not provide some charts which chartNew.js provides